# How to loss textfield focus when I click other place in window in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, focus, textfield

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQZ76.png)
The Code create a window,and there is a textfield in window.it is a search box.when I click the blank place or other place,I want that the textfield loss focus.

```html
    HBox pane = new HBox();
  
  Label lb_search = new Label("search:");
  TextField tf_search = new TextField();
  
  pane.getChildren().addAll(lb_search,tf_search);
  
  Scene scene = new Scene(pane,400,200);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.setTitle("search");
  primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, only controls can get focus in JavaFX.  However, you can change this with `setFocusTraversable`.  Try changing this on the Node the TextField is contained in.